# Cordova dialog with single choice selection

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to replicate android native app single choice selection dialog via `cordovaDialog` but fail to find any documentation about that. Anyone know how can i replicate it when developing in ionic framework 1?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u r using cordova or ionic. You can easily do it with html select tag. There is no need of additional code for dialog.

```
<select id='yourselect'>
<option value='coke'>coke</option>
<option value='pepsi'>pepsi</option>
</select>
```

And use javascript to detect selection

Comment: I am using a button click to trigger the effect. And thus the select option should not be appearing in the ui. How can it trigger the effect of select then? `<button ng-click="openSingleSelectDialog()">Click here to open select dialog</button>`

Comment: There should be some error in your function. First try to display alert or console to detect function call. Then put code to show select.

Comment: And to show select as dialog you have to click on that select. Hence you have to call click trigger function for that select inside your function that you are currently using.